# Irish visa data sharing

Tags: visas, uk, ireland, family

Friend wife applied Irish Spouse visa and sign application summary.her husband provided unsigned sponsorship letter but they refused her visa as they said husband living in UK.
Visa application was for wife. Husband never sign any consent so why and how they cross check it. Husband is eu citizen and eu citizen have free movement.
Personally I never seen anything like this as per my knowledge they should ask her husband consent before doing cross checks.
Any opinion?
Husband doing business in UK and frequently travel between Ireland and UK.(he mostly spend time in Ireland)

Q. Can Irish immigration authorities get sponsor(husband) activity details from UK without getting his Consent? As applicant(wife) signed consent form but not husband?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the wife wanted to live in Ireland on her own while the EU-citizen husband lives in the UK, and expected to receive a spouse visa on that claim? Seriously?

Comment: When applying for a spouse visa the applicant naturally has to provide information about their spouse. Not sure why you think the country should not be allowed to check that information. Do you have sources that lead you to believe so?

Comment: Just to point out, if the husband is travelling directly to the UK from Ireland, there wouldn't be any UK immigration data. The UK does not routinely perform border control on flights from Ireland. More likely, the data would have come from Irish border records, ie, they would have recorded the husband on his return from the UK to Ireland, because Ireland does perform border control on flights from the UK. Hence, no data from the UK would be needed, and may not even exist.

Answer (score 3):

The [Electronic Immigration Network](https://www.ein.org.uk/news/home-office-share-immigration-data-ireland-under-new-memorandum-understanding), a UK secondary source, says in 2014 the answer became "Yes, the UK and Ireland can share immigration data." The first few lines of the article are:

> **Home Office to share immigration data with Ireland under new          Memorandum of Understanding**
>
> 07 October 2014 EIN
>
> The Home Office announced yesterday that a new Memorandum of Understanding (MOU) has been signed with the Republic of Ireland to strengthen the Common Travel Area.
>
> A Home Office press release says that the new MOU will allow the UK and Ireland to share data and exchange information which will be used to inform and determine immigration decisions.

The same information appeared concurrently in [The Irish Times](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/social-affairs/visa-deal-with-uk-to-boost-visitor-numbers-1.1952934).

Comment: I would add a practical word to say that the best response to the situation presented in the question is not to challenge the information sharing but to reapply with additional evidence to make a stronger showing that the husband does in fact reside in Ireland (or perhaps appeal if the evidence presented in the first application was misinterpreted).  In other words, the dispute should be about whether his presence in Ireland in fact constitutes residence rather than about how the Irish authorities got their information.